# Wix trying to close Wix application before restarting after .Net installation

Tags: wix, restartmanager

I am having a WIX setup which does following in order:

1. Installs Windows Updates
2. Restart
3. Continue Wix App
4. Installs .Net 4.6.1
5. Gives a prompt "This app is stopping system to restart" with options Restart Anyway / Cancel. Want to run 7 after Restart without user interaction
6. Restart without Prompt
7. Installs

ControlCenter

Restart Anyway closes the Wix application and does not continue my app after restart. Cancels cancel the app and show failed.

1. /passive (restarts with no UI but with prompt)
2. /q (restart with prompt and other UI interaction which I dont want)
3. /norestart /q (does not restart the system)

Following is my node:

- List item

< ExePackage Id="NetFx461Web"
                  DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1"
                  Compressed="no" Cache="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Protocol="netfx4"
                  SourceFile="..\WinUpdates\Media\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/passive /chainingpackage ControlCenter"
                  DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx461WebDetectCondition)" 
                  InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx461WebInstallCondition)">
            < ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="1641" />
            < ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="3010" />

Also used following but no use

< Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable"/>

If this is not the right forum, then please do let me know

Comment: No response... This is where I got stuck finally .. :(

Comment: This finally worked.. Only thing is Restart Anyway comes for a very small time after which my installer shows failed and has to manually restart. It seems fine for now but looking for better answer.